# What is the correct way to analyze this data in a mixed model approach?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, experiment-design, biostatistics

I have an experiment with rates of an waste in complete randomized blocks designs, with evaluation of soil fertility and tree heights/diameters over the years. Which is the best model to fit this data?

```r
Rates (ton/ha) - 0; 10; 20; 30; 40 
Blocks - 1; 2; 3; 4 
Years - 0; 1; 5; 9; 14
```

I used the `lme`:

Model for all data

```r
m1 <- lme(pH ~ Rate*(Years+I(Years^2)), random = ~ 1 + 
          Years + I(Years^2)|Block, data = Compilado, method = "ML", 
          control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))
```

Model for each rate over the years

```r
m0 <- lme(pH ~ (Anos+I(Anos^2)), random = ~ 1|Bloco, data = Compilado_0, 
          method = "ML", control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))
```

or

```r
m0 <- lme(pH ~ Anos), random = ~ 1|Bloco, data = Compilado_0, method = "ML",
          control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))
```

Is this correct?